# The host is disposed and cannot be used when running process at Service bus

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have an Azure Function triggered by Service Bus (standard plan). Most of the time it works OK, but when I do a load test with around 100 messages to a topic, and find that some processes have been stopped immediately and the exception is thrown as below, while some processes are still done.

Here is a detailed exception logs from Insight:

problemId:

```
DryIoc.ContainerException at DryIoc.Throw.It
```

outerMessage:

```
The host is disposed and cannot be used. Disposed object: 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.DependencyInjection.ScopedResolver'; Found IListener in stack trace: 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.Listeners.ServiceBusListener, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

innermostMessage:

```
Container is disposed and should not be used: Container is disposed. You may include Dispose stack-trace into the message via: container.With(rules => rules.WithCaptureContainerDisposeStackTrace())
```

So what is the problem with it and how could we prevent the process be stopped

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `DryIoc` and not the built-in IoC from Azure Functions? Looks like there might be a scoping issue. We're going to need some more information on how you're registering services and using the IoC container.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any idea about DryIoc and built-in IoC. For services, I use Function App with
App Service Plan: ElasticPremium (EP1), Operating System: Windows, ElasticPremium, Stack: Nodejs 12 (32bits) and Service bus (standard tier)